# Twitter oAuth Invalid request token

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I'm using the TwitterOAuth PHP library to connect my web page to Twitter, to retrieve authenticated user's data, but it's not working at all, I've been trying since yesterday and I've still not figured out how to do it.

This is my code:

```
    $twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    $credentials = $twitter->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => OAUTH_CALLBACK));
    $url = $twitter->url("oauth/authorize", array("oauth_token" => $credentials['oauth_token']));
    $_SESSION["oauth_token"] = $credentials["oauth_token"];
    $_SESSION["oauth_token_secret"] = $credentials["oauth_token_secret"];
    ?>
    <input type="button" name="contactTwitter" id="contactTwitter" onClick='window.location="<?php echo $url; ?>"' value="Connect to Twitter!"/>
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['oauth_verifier'])) :
        $at=$twitter->oauth("oauth/access_token", array("oauth_verifier" => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']));
        var_dump($at);
    endif;
```

And it's not working at all. I've found lots of results to solve TwitterOAuth issues, but no one has helped me. I've understood Twitter API's functioning like
sending `request_token`, receiving `token_verifiers` and obtaining `access_tokens` but it's not working here.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved.
I used another PHP file to get the TwitterOAuth callback result, which sends the access_token to my previous page which wasn't working.
In case that someone will need this, I'm posting the `callback.php` code:

```
require_once('config.php');
session_start();
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
$request_token = array();
$request_token['oauth_token'] = $_SESSION['oauth_token'];
$request_token['oauth_token_secret'] = $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'];

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(TW_CONSUMER_KEY, TW_CONSUMER_SECRET, $request_token['oauth_token'], $request_token['oauth_token_secret']);
$access_token = $connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", array("oauth_verifier" => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']));

if (200 == $connection->lastHttpCode()) {
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
    unset($_SESSION['oauth_token']);
    unset($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
    $_SESSION['status'] = 'verified';
} else {
    session_destroy();
}

header('Location:./reg.php?st=3');
```

Than, in the registration page i just re-use the stored `$_SESSION['access_token']` which I've found before.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. It was the final bit of help I needed to get over the line. Bizarre this took me so long.

Comment: In case someone else shows up here and, like me, doesn't find the solution here immediately obvious: 1) After requesting a token, you need to save that token data somewhere. 2) Then when you're getting an access token, you have to pass the request token data to the `TwitterOAuth` instantiation.

Comment: I use same methods but twitter reject stored  `$_SESSION['access_token']` i got sae message `'Invalid request token.'`

Comment: @SalemF don't know if u need to write another question for this, maybe try posting your code. Are you sure you can't find something on Stackoverflow? By the way, I re-used Twitter somewhere else for my projects, and, have to say, the docs here: https://twitteroauth.com/ became better, I'm sure you can find out a solution there

Comment: I think I'll post my Q here , but mys issue was very similar as I sucess send status to other user account but storing access_token still confusied me , I think oauth API regnew it with every `$connection->oauth` request

Comment: @SalemF Everytime you request another code, the previous one ( or the one already saved in your session ) become invalid. Double check this, because it's a very common problem

Comment: Yes  I was stock with `oauth_verifier` that sent back to callback url . I was thought it the same code of `oauth_token_secret` that lead me crazy few hours . anyway app now work as the client request it , to allow multiple users uplad and sheduler their tweets .